# How to remove from union?

Tags: typescript

Given a union, is it possible to remove a union?

```
type V = { cat: string } | { dog: string }

type X = Omit<V, 'dog'>

const exampleA: X = { cat: '23456' }
const exampleB: X = { dog: '23456' }
```

Comment: The code in this question doesn't quite constitute a [mcve].  I'm guessing you want `exampleA` to compile with no errors and `exampleB` to be an error?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your use case, you could define `ExcludeWithKeys<T, K>` like this:

```
type ExcludeWithKeys<T, K extends PropertyKey> = Exclude<T, Partial<Record<K, any>>>;
```

or the equivalent

```
type ExcludeWithKeys<T, K extends PropertyKey> = T extends { [P in K]?: any } ? never : T;
```

and use it:

```
type X = ExcludeWithKeys<V, 'dog'>;
// type X = { cat: string }

const exampleA: X = { cat: '23456' }; // okay
const exampleB: X = { dog: '23456' }; // error
```

I'm assuming that's what you want for the example code.  Note that there are likely plenty of edge cases so you should tweak `ExcludeWithKeys<T, K>` as necessary.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAalC8UDeUDGBDYAuKBnYATgJYB2A5lAL5QA+yUAJgPZk77HlUCwAUL6JCgBRAB6oANgFcGEAOpFgACwDSEELgA8AFQA0UZVAgjgEEg1xQACgSaQCoVSAB8CKFsPHT5+gG1LUUn0AXQB+HHQSECooEKgSCAA3CAIoHC1efnBoAA1XUQlpOQUVNU0YPQByZjIKpwBuXgB6RqgBHNcUDGw8QlIKSl4oXlQmEnwPdABbMHEIAEEcXMROzBwKgCYAZgAWAFYANgqqOqhmqCYAa3QQYdHxoymZiAAhRY7GFjWtvcPj05bkjYCBkeEA)